# How to call a script from inside CPP code in linux

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ coding using linux.Hence, my apologies if my question is trivial.

I need some help regarding calling some script/executable from inside a cpp file.

I downloaded few libraries (Blas, Lapack, libtsnnls-2.3.3). Configured and made executable. This executable was created when I configured and compiled libtsnnls-2.3.3.

I can call from command line:

> > cd /home/dkumar/libtsnnls-2.3.3/tsnnls
> >
> > ./genb_test

Now, I want to call the same command from a cpp file. It's something similar to "HelloWorld.cpp"

My Attempt (modified based on suggestion of @Biffer @timrau:

```
// 'Hello World!' program 
 #include <stdio.h>  /* defines FILENAME_MAX */
 #include <cstdlib>   /* MODIFIED std::system */

 #include <iostream>
 #ifdef _MSC_VER
    #include "direct.h" 
    #define GetCurrentDir _getcwd // window ??
 #else
    #include "unistd.h"
        #define GetCurrentDir getcwd
 #endif


int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;


  // const char *ParentFolder = "/home/dkumar/All_Matlab_Codes_DKU";
  const char *ParentFolder = "/home/dkumar/libtsnnls-2.3.3/tsnnls/";

  int res3 = chdir(ParentFolder);


  // exceuting the command('./genb_test')  
  std::system('./genb_test');

return 0;
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
HelloWorld.cpp:36:10: warning: character constant too long for its type [enabled by default]
   system('./genb_test');
          ^
HelloWorld.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
HelloWorld.cpp:36:23: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
   system('./genb_test');
                       ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/cstdlib:72:0,
                 from HelloWorld.cpp:4:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:717:12: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘int system(const char*)’ [-fpermissive]
 extern int system (const char *__command) __wur;
```

Comment: Or [`std::system()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system).

Comment: @Biffen I implemented your suggestion and now, I get error. Please see the main question which I have modified.

Comment: In c++ `'` is used for characters and `"` is used for strings.  Edit `system('./genb_test')` to `system("./genb_test")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In c++ ' is used for characters (`'a'`) and " is used for strings (`"aaaa"`).

If you edit `system('./genb_test')` to be `system("./genb_test")` it might work.

Answer (score 0):

there is a function named `system` which could start a shell process to run your script, to do this, you need first include `cstdlib` header and then call the `system` function in your code

example

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    system("./myscript.sh");
}
```

The function system need a parameter of type std::string or a C-style string, so you will need the double quotation mark

Comment: you should replace ' with " :)

Answer (score 0):

You have single ' when calling your script. You want double "

```
#include <cstdlib>   /* MODIFIED std::system */
int main()
{
    // executing the command("./genb_test")  
    std::system("./genb_test");
    return 0;
}
```